# How to move a single element inside a SDL_Renderer?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I want to code a game, with SDL2 and C.

But I don't know how to update the character, when he moves.

I tried to update it with the code below.

But the problem is that it deletes everything, the character but also all the content of the renderer.

And, if I don't add SDL_RenderClear(renderer1), the character is displayed one more time everytime he moves, because his last position hasn't been cleared.

```
//Before, there is an event checking loop
if(keyPressed == SDLK_RIGHT){
  rectMegaman.x += 20;
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer1);
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer1, megaman, NULL, &rectMegaman);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer1);
}
```

So, how can I update the character, without having to delete all the renderer content?

Comment: Common approach is to redraw everything on each frame, as in most cases pretty much entire screen changes, to some extent. You can of course redraw only part where your 'character' is now, and where it was vefore (what should be here - e.g. background), but then you have to consider double buffering (bonus point - is it triple?), which may be very hard. Some software, e.g. blender, tries to do that, with various success on different hardware/drivers, and option to use ordinary double buffer with full redraw, because it fails far too often.

Answer (score 0):

By far the most common way to render pretty much anything, with the SDL or any other graphics library, is to clear and redraw the entire screen. Every game (that I'm aware of) does that at least 30 times per second and it works just fine. It means your calls to `SDL_RenderClear` and `SDL_RenderPresent` should be outside any conditional drawing (you usually only have one call to each). The general idea is to call `SDL_RenderClear`, then call `SDL_RenderCopy` for everything you need drawn, and at the end, call `SDL_RenderPresent` before starting over again.